# How to display number of visitors?

Tags: count

I have an application uploaded on a web server.
I want to display the total number of visitors who have been to my application link.
Any idea?

Comment: You need to provide more details, mate!

Comment: @Abdul you should try google analytic follow this link http://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code it uses cookie check and you can update parameters like for how long a visitor is considered unique  :

http://discussion.accuwebhost.com/how-tos/479-how-write-simple-php-hit-counter-displays-number-visits-your-website.html

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to display visitors from data table from your server. Use
>   php
>
> $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password"); if (!$con)
>   {   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());   } echo "Connected to
>   MySQL
> "; mysql_select_db("adil") or die(mysql_error()); echo
>   "Connected to Database";
>
> $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test"); echo ""; while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   {   echo
>   "" . $row['visitor'] . "" . "" . $row['col2'] .
>   "";  // echo "
> ";   } echo "";
>   mysql_close($con);